# Encoding issue with AJAX request

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, utf-8, character-encoding

A search is run on this website via AJAX, and I'm having issues with non-English characters.

I have this code here:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "GET",
    "url": '<%= url_for({:action => "update_search"}) %>?',
    "data": query_string,
    "dataType": 'script',
    "success": function() {
        search_done();
    }
});
```

The query string contains the term to search for and a few other parameters. For testing purposes, I have an `alert` that pops up in the success function on the JS side, and a `puts` statement as the very first line in the `update_search` method on the Rails side.

Here is the weirdness that I'm having issues with:

When searching in English, everything works fine; I see the alert and the output from the `puts` in the Rails console. When searching in Chinese, I still see the success `alert`, but nothing from `update_search`. In Rails console, I see `Invalid HTTP format, parsing fails` from Mongrel.

What is the correct way to pass foreign characters back to the server via URL parameter?

Rails version is 2.3.10 if it makes a difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This](http://www.webtoolkit.info/javascript-utf8.html) is what I used to fix this.

Comment: hey, seems it was indeed an encoding issue after all. You can accept your own answer.

Comment: SO makes me wait 24 hours to accept my own answer. I'll accept it tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

You should do it like that:

```
$.ajax({
    "type": "GET",
    "url": '<%= url_for({:action => "update_search"}) %>',
    "data": query_string,
    "dataType": 'script',
    "success": function() {
        search_done();
    }
});
```

Notice separation of `query_string` from the URL. According to [the documentation of `.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), jQuery does it automatically, so you do not need to deal with everything. It may be helpful.

Tell me if it helped.

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem, but I do like the separation of data here, so I'll change it to this. Thanks for the tip!